# JavaScript. loop through subsets of divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this piece of HTML (which is actually a lot bigger) but I use this as a sample to demonstrate my problem. So what I want to do is to loop through all 'div.col' and for every div inside that has a 'data-text' which is set I want to push that 'data-text' to an array.

How can I do that?

```
<div class="holder">
    <div class="col">
        <div data-text=""></div>
        <div data-text="lorem"></div>
        <div data-text=""></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div data-text="hey"></div>
        <div data-text=""></div>
        <div data-text="hello"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div data-text=""></div>
        <div data-text="lorem"></div>
        <div data-text=""></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this snippet:

```js
var items = [];

$('div.col div[data-text]').each(function() {
  var text = $(this).data("text");
  
  if (text && text.length > 0) {
    items.push(text);
  }
});

console.log(items);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="holder">
    <div class="col">
        <div data-text=""></div>
        <div data-text="lorem"></div>
        <div data-text=""></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div data-text="hey"></div>
        <div data-text=""></div>
        <div data-text="hello"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div data-text=""></div>
        <div data-text="lorem"></div>
        <div data-text=""></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pure js approach.

```js
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.holder .col div[data-text]:not([data-text=""])'),
    res = Array.from(elems).map(v => v.getAttribute('data-text'));

    console.log(res);
```

```html
<div class="holder">
    <div class="col">
        <div data-text=""></div>
        <div data-text="lorem"></div>
        <div data-text=""></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div data-text="hey"></div>
        <div data-text=""></div>
        <div data-text="hello"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div data-text=""></div>
        <div data-text="lorem"></div>
        <div data-text=""></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map()` and `get()` to return array.

```js
var arr = $('.holder div').map(function() {
  if ($(this).data('text')) return $(this).data('text');
}).get()

console.log(arr)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="holder">
  <div class="col">
    <div data-text=""></div>
    <div data-text="lorem"></div>
    <div data-text=""></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div data-text="hey"></div>
    <div data-text=""></div>
    <div data-text="hello"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div data-text=""></div>
    <div data-text="lorem"></div>
    <div data-text=""></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you can select only the elements that have a `data-text` attribute with a value then `map()` the resulting elements to an array. Try this:

```js
var arr = $('.holder .col div[data-text]:not([data-text=""])').map(function() {
  return $(this).data('text');
}).get();
console.log(arr)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="holder">
  <div class="col">
    <div data-text=""></div>
    <div data-text="lorem"></div>
    <div data-text=""></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div data-text="hey"></div>
    <div data-text=""></div>
    <div data-text="hello"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div data-text=""></div>
    <div data-text="lorem"></div>
    <div data-text=""></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I hope you don't mind if I use this `not` selector in my solution. I like it.